# What is exactly a transaction initiator and executor in UVM port and export?

Tags: interface, system-verilog, uvm

Screenshot from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doRowGhiGUc&t=736s).
[image]

Whereas in UVM, sequencer has an import/export and driver has a port. Sequencer seems to be the transaction initiator and driver as the executor (as it is finally assigning transaction to the DUT). Is this right? Image from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXhHW000IeI&t=1121s):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it reversed. The driver calls `get()`/`get_next_item()` methods which *initiates* the transaction, and the sequencer provides the ***imp**lementation* that executes the `get`.

In TLM-speak the *initiator* is the place in your code were you call the method; and the *executor* **is** the method being called.

- A get() initiates a transfer where the transaction moves from the *executor* to the *initiator*
- A put() initiates a transfer where the transaction moves from the *initiator* to the *executor*

I believe the UVM uses the term **imp** rather than **import** referring to the implementation of the method to be called. This is so you don't confuse it with an **export**, which is just an intermediary providing a handle to an *imp* to connect to a *port*.

Most components have two sides to them, acting as both initiator and executor. A UVM driver is translating TLM transactions it get()s and executing them as pin-level DUT transactions.

Comment: Thus, unlike the traditional SV TB, where generator has put and driver has get, in UVM, it is the driver's get next item call which retrieves the next transaction once the finish item (seems to be passive) in sequence is done. Thank you Dave for providing an insightful answer!

Comment: In the UVM, the sequence is the generator, and put() is split into start_item/finish_item. See https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/driver/sequence-api

Comment: I don't have the full access to view what you have just shared.